# ImageField not getting deleted when save button is pressed : Django-admin

Tags: django-admin

i have the following files

models.py

Class Trip(models.Model)

```
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Tags this trip as a featured trip.')
top_ten_trip = models.BooleanField(default=False)
header_image = models.ImageField(help_text='This is the image shown when viewing the details for this trip.', upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
map_image = models.ImageField(help_text='The map image for this trip.', upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
.....
```

and so on

admin.py

class TripAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
list_display = ('name', 'code', 'category', 'supplier', 'active', 'featured', 'top_ten_trip',)
search_fields = ('name', 'code',)
list_filter = ('category', 'featured', 'top_ten_trip',)
filter_horizontal = ('countries', 'related_trips',)
```

The field appear with browse button in admin something like this
Header image: Currently: images/comfort_japan.jpg
Change: Delete this file

Map image: Currently: images/map_japan_.jpg
Change: Delete this file

Now the Problem :-
When i click on Delete this imagefile( images/comfort_japan.jpg ) it get removed for that instant but does not deleted when i press save button on admin.

I want when i click on delete this file and press save it should get deleted.

What mistake i am doing or what am i missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This was intentionally changed in Django 1.3, see
[Django Ticket #15224](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15224).
You need to implement file deletion yourself. Check related posts:

- [How do I get Django Admin to delete files when I remove an object from the database/model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372934/how-do-i-get-django-admin-to-delete-files-when-i-remove-an-object-from-the-datab)
- [Django admin: Add a "remove file" field for Image- or FileFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657149/django-admin-add-a-remove-file-field-for-image-or-filefields)

Comment: What i want is the ImageField which Django1.4b contains.A checkbox which ask for clear image .How can i achieve that ? I am looking through Django 1.4b code really hard to figure out what they have done.I am in Django1.2.5 .How can i use post_save signal to achieve this

Comment: @the_game The Clear checkbox (appearing next to the image name if `blank=True` was set on the ImageField) when selected only removes the image from the model (db) but not deleting it from the disk. To override this with signals check [this](http://obroll.com/automatically-delete-file-in-filefield-django-1-3-when-object-record-deleted/)

Comment: Write i agree it will only remove and not delete. This snippet also removes but not delete. As i have searched remove is the better approach rather than delete but thanks i made some concept on signals

Answer (score 0):

Hi All I solved my problem by using snippet 1633

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1633/ .It works pretty fine.